# React Native: iOS archive build failed in Appcircle CI

Tags: ios, react-native, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

iOS archive build generation is succeed when I generate from xcode but it fails in [Appcircle.io](https://appcircle.io/) with the following error. If I disable "use_flipper" from the PodFile, "pre_install" & "post_install" scripts are not running and build is failed in my xcode itself

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

    CompileC .../_appcircle_temp/appcircle_export_archive/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyProject/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Flipper-Folly.build/Objects-normal/armv7/VirtualEventBase.o .../_appcircle_temp/Repository/ios/Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/io/async/VirtualEventBase.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

(1 failure)

warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: Cannot Load File: Failed to open diagnostics file (in target 'Flipper-Folly' from project 'Pods')

warning: no rule to process file '.../_appcircle_temp/Repository/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/CMakeLists.txt' of type 'text' for architecture 'armv7' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')

warning: no rule to process file '.../_appcircle_temp/Repository/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'armv7' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')

warning: no rule to process file '.../_appcircle_temp/Repository/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'armv7' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')

warning: no rule to process file '.../_appcircle_temp/Repository/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/CMakeLists.txt' of type 'text' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')

warning: no rule to process file '.../_appcircle_temp/Repository/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')

warning: no rule to process file '.../_appcircle_temp/Repository/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')

@@[error] 3/22/2021 3:24:36 AM EXCEPTION

@@[error] @@[error] Process exit with error code: 1

@@[error] 42gez13d.r50 Error at step: Xcodebuild for Devices

@@[error] EXCEPTION: @@[error] Process exit with error code: 1
```